# How an Affine hull can be represented by an Affine set?

Tags: affine-geometry, affine-schemes

[image]

Please see the image for detail of the question.

Comment: perhaps example 2.1 of convex optimization book (by Stephen Boyd) will be a help

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful @Frank Moses

Comment: You are welcome. If you found your answer then please post it.

Comment: Actually, I'm new here. does not how to add images from the comment or any method how to write down the equations here.
But as a reference, I have just directly followed the book example you have adviced

Comment: I think on this page you can find a link "Answer your Question". You can click it and then a new page will open where you can even attach the images.

Comment: BTW affine hull itself is an affine set

Answer (score 1):

[With the help of @Frank Moses This image may give some hints to the exact answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f8Qp.png)

Please click the image, and pardon my inability to write down equations in this platform, as i'm new here